# JSON is diluted with garbage on Response

Tags: php, json

I use Symfony 5.2. (composer update is done)

PHP 7.4

Docker container with PHP + NGINX reverse proxy Docker container.

There is a problem, which is that the controller gives an invalid JSON response.

But the problem occurs on the prod, not locally. And not every answer with a broken JSON but is periodically, I cannot guess, maybe for the third time, or maybe for the 5th, or for the 7th, but constantly. The controller itself receives a JSON string as argument, and outputs a JSON string as output (new JsonResponse($data)).

Here is the argument for the controller

```
{order: "22", productType: "2", productId: "64"}
```

Here is what the controller should eventually give away

```
{"order":22,"count":1,"price":5000,"currency":"RUB","cart":[{"id":923,"order":22,"productType":2,"productId":64,"count":1,"created":{"date":"2021-02-03 19:06:39.634912","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]}
```

And here's what really gives

```
{"order":"22","product_type":"2","product_id":"64"}{"order":22,"count":1,"price":5000,"currency":"RUB","cart":[{"id":923,"order":22,"productType":2,"productId":64,"count":1,"created":{"date":"2021-02-03 19:06:39.634912","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]}
```

That is, my argument is added to the beginning of the JSON response. Note that there is no comma after the garbage string, and the indexes in the garbage string look like snake_case, although all the other content is like camelCase

In the beginning, I thought that maybe it's in NGINX, but everything is OK there. I used the tcpdump utility to check what exactly gives the PHP container in which Symfony. And there is broken JSON.

I also saved in the log data that is serialized array, but in the logs everything is ok.

1. I write to the log right before **new JsonResponse()**, a valid array is
   written without garbage.
2. I create my EventListener for the Response event with a priority of
   -10000 (so that it would be called last) and in it I also write the resulting response to the log, and there is a valid JSON
3. I'm right in the main file public/index.php before the script's
   response, I also write its response to the log, and there is also a
   valid JSON without garbage

Tell me how can I fix it?

```
/**
 * @Route("/add-product-to-cart", name="add_product_to_cart", methods={"POST"})
 *
 * @param Request         $request
 * @param OrderProvider   $orderProvider
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function addProductToCart(Request $request, OrderProvider $orderProvider, LoggerInterface $logger): JsonResponse
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    try {
        $cart = $orderProvider
            ->order($data['order'])
            ->addProduct($data['product_type'], $data['product_id'], $data['count'] ?? 1)
            ->cartsAsArray()
        ;

        $result = [
            'order' => $orderProvider->orderId(),
            'count' => $orderProvider->count(),
            'price' => $orderProvider->price(),
            'currency' => $orderProvider->currency()->getCode(),
            'cart' => $cart,
        ];

        // Тут пишу в лог массив. Там все чтеко !!!
        $logger->error('Server return: ' . json_encode($result));
        
        return new JsonResponse($result);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        'error' => 1,
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest searching your code for an errant `echo` somewhere - this looks like the sort of thing that happens when a temporary debugging print statement gets left in and sends output before the _real_ output

Comment: Seems you have some `echo` anywhere in your code that's output the request data.

Comment: If there is some ECHO in my PHP code, why there is no invalid JSON in log here in my controller

$logger->error('Server return: ' . json_encode($result));

Comment: Solved. There was virus Kdevtmpfsi on the server.